# Passing data between Fragments with bundle object

Tags: java, android, bundle

I have two blank activites which holds two fragments.One activity is having adapter and it is acting as Tabactivity with adapter inside.

I want to pass data with intent and bundle inside.
When user enter email in Activity 1 and press button, email is going to appear on TextView inside Activity 2.

Here is exception I get :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.presenter.utils.ui.AutoResizeTextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                            at com.presenter.view.fragment.ForgotPasswordFragmentComplete.onCreate(ForgotPasswordFragmentComplete.java:50)
                                                            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2075)
```

I have created Intent and bundle:

```
@Bind(R.id.btn_forgot)
    AppCompatButton btn_forgot;
    @Bind(R.id.forgot_edittext)
    AppCompatEditText editEmail;

public void onButtonClick() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(".presenter.view.activity.ForgotPasswordCompleted");

   intent.putExtra("email", editEmail.getText().toString());


   ForgotPasswordFragment fragment = new ForgotPasswordFragment();
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("email",editEmail.getText().toString());
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

startActivity(intent);
    }

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".presenter.view.activity.ForgotPasswordCompleted"
   android:label="Forgot"
   android:launchMode="singleTask"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

 <intent-filter>
   <action android:name=".presenter.view.activity.ForgotPasswordCompleted"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

I have binded textview with Dagger,added String getName and implemented intent and bundle in fragment 2:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
        if ((bd != null)){
            String getName = (String) bd.get("email");
            resentTxt.setText(getName);
        }
```

Comment: You did nothing with neither intent nor fragment created in onButtonClick

Comment: I was trying everthing, what should I do with them?@Selvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten to write this line

```
InjectorClass.inject(this);
```

in onCreate.

Comment: Thanks, I will do it..Do you think that injection is making problem? @Harish Gyanani

Comment: Yes, you are getting NullPointerException because AutoResizeTextView is null.

Comment: I can see that from exception, but do you think it is problem with injecting Class in fragment 2?

Comment: One activity should not send bundle data to a fragment which is part of another activity. Send data from activity A to Activity B, then send data from activity B to  fragment (ForgotPasswordFragment).